# Using an enum in a POCO class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I'm developing an Entity Framework 6.1.3 library with .NET Framework 4.0 and C#.

I have a question about if it is possible to use an enum in a POCO class.

I have this class and enum:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public byte MyClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte CodeType { get; set; }
    public byte HelperCodeType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Code> Codes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HelperCode> HelperCodes { get; set; }
}

public enum CodeTypes : byte
{
    Generated = 0,
    PrePrinted = 1,
    PrePrintedAndPreLoaded = 2,
    PreLoaded = 3,
    NotUsed = 4
}
```

I'm wondering if I can change `MyClass` fields `CodeType` and `HelperCodeType` with the enum type instead of `byte`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public byte MyClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CodeTypes CodeType { get; set; }
    public CodeTypes HelperCodeType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Code> Codes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HelperCode> HelperCodes { get; set; }
}
```

Is it a good idea to use enums instead of byte in a POCO class?

Comment: Try and find out :-) If it works, then you don't have to do any manual conversions from byte to the enum type.

Comment: BTW, why is the PK a byte as well? Are you expecting less then 256 records?

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting no more than four or five records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework supports enums since some time (since version 5 if I remember correctly). In the database, it will use the numeric type of the enum as column type, in your case it will add `byte` columns.

I think enums are a good idea if some business logic depends on the field.

Comment: Lets say I have the `enum` with `int`, can I use the same enum item in my query? I want to query like `_context.MyClass.where(ent => ent.CodeType  == CodeTypes.Generated)`.

Comment: Yes that should work with EF 5 or later.